# How to use two service classes for a WCF REST Service?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I have a REST Service built with WCF Rest Service Template.

I am curious if it is possible to have to service classes in my project and register them in the RegisterRoutes() in Global.Asax.

I tried this but only Service1 will resolve:

```
    private void RegisterRoutes()
{                  
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service2", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service2)));
}
```

Is this possible or should all my service methods reside on one class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is possible, but in your scenario above, the first ServiceRoute will catch calls to the second Service (Service2), because it looks like calls to /Service2 are actually operations on Service1.

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service1", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service2", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service2)));
```

should work...

alternatively,

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Service2", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service2)));
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(Service1)));
```

should work too...but it doesn't seem like such a good idea in terms of ambiguity.

Comment: I should have waited 5 minutes to ask this as I found the solution pretty quickly. It's good to document the solution here though.